# Issue with printing clusters using igraph

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, igraph

I have a graph g and I want to find the clusters in this graph using igraph, Here's my code:

```
g = Graph.Read_Ncol('karate.txt', directed=False)
p = g.community_label_propagation()
```

I tried to print the clusters in 2 ways, first:

```
print(p)
```

second:

```
for idx, cluster in enumerate(p):
    print(cluster)
```

Here's the output of the first one:

```
[0] 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 19, 21
[1] 2, 8, 31, 30, 9, 27, 28, 32, 33, 14, 15, 18, 20, 22, 23, 25, 29, 24, 26
[2] 5, 16
```

and the output of the second one is:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[2, 8, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
[5, 22]
```

I was wondering why the clusters are different in these two outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing different data structures.

In the first,you are printing the entire clustering. Apparently,someone of the igraph authors decided that printing the cluster number is a good idea, too.

In the second case, that would be your responsibility.

Note that the output of

```
a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
print a
for row in a: print row
```

is not the same either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not my point. look at the third cluster for example. in the first output the third cluster is [5,16] and in the second output the third cluster is [5,22]

Comment: Probably one uses the node labels (that happen to be numbers) and the other uses array indexes. Can you map your data to labels?

Comment: Thanks 
The first one uses the names of vertices (same as input file) and the second one uses ids of vertices